# Catch event thru interface with vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to add a user control containing a simple button in a form and catch the button click event from the form. Here is my actual code :

Interface :

```
Public Interface IPlugInterface
     Event Test()
End Interface
```

UserControl :

```
Public Class Plug

    Implements IPlugInterface

    Private Event Test() Implements IPlugInterface.Test

    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button.Click
        RaiseEvent Test()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Main Form :

```
Public Class Form

    Private Plugin As New Plug

    Private Sub Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Controls.Add(Plugin)
    End Sub

End Class
```

How to tell the main form to catch the "Test" event sent by the Plug class ?

Comment: Why are you declaring the event `Private` if you want to refer to it outside the class?  Also, I hope that the code you have provided is a simplification of your actual code.  There's a convention that should be followed when implementing events.  You can read about that [here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/11/defining-and-raising-custom-events.html).

Comment: As for how to handle the event, it's an event just like any other, so you handle it like any other. You've not demonstrated that you have made any attempt, so it would appear that you haven't actually done appropriate research on how to handle events.

Comment: Yes the code is a simplification. Actually, real code does dynamically load the "Plug" control as a dll on startup. That's why I want to use an Interface. I achieve to send params from host to plug on startup but do not know how to send from plug to host after startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: As noted in the comments, first change the Type to IPlugInInterface.  Examples updated below:

You can use AddHandler or WithEvents to wire up the event handler as explained in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973905.aspx).

AddHandler example:

```
Private PlugIn As IPlugInInterface = New Plug()

AddHandler Plugin.Test, AddressOf YourEventHandler
```

and then:

```
Private Sub YourEventHandler()
End Sub
```

WithEvents example:

```
Private WithEvents Plugin As IPlugInInterface = New Plug()
```

and then:

```
Private Sub YourEventHandler() Handles Plugin.Test
End Sub
```

Comment: You might need to cast `Plugin` to `IPlugInterface` given that the event is private in `Plugin`.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for. You can read my comment above : I need to use the IPlugInterface to manage events.

Comment: @kloug Interfaces don't raise events, but rather the implementations of the interfaces do.  You might be better off using a MustInherit (abstract) class for the type of control you're looking for.

Comment: @kloug So you'll be working through a variable of type `IPlugInterface`.  You can assign an instance of anything that implements that interface to the variable.  You can make the variable `WithEvents` or use `AddHandler`; in either case, the syntax should be the same.

Comment: Thanks @Craig and N0Alias your advices helped me to solve that !

Answer (score 0):

Ok thank's to everyone here's how I modified the Form class to make it work :

```
Public Class Form

    Private WithEvents PlugInterface As IPlugInterface = New Plug

    Private Sub Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Me.Controls.Add(PlugInterface)

    End Sub

    Private Sub TestEvent() Handles PlugInterface.Test

        MsgBox("Event !")

    End Sub

End Class
```

Hope I can adapt this to my real code with loading plug control as dll on startup.